# Cant get show/hide to work on table tr (jquery)

Tags: jquery

Hello all you great brains out there, hope someone can help me!

I'm trying to set up a order form where people can choose to get the order delivered or get it themselves.

If they chose to get it delivered the order form should display adress part of the form if not the adress part of the form should be hidden.

The page in question:
http://www.gordions.dk/bestilling.html (the bottom of the page)
Its the `<tr class="adresse">` im trying to hide

i have tried several solutions found here on stackoverflow but can't get any of them to work

Latest try is with

```
$('tr.adresse').hide();
```

to hide the the `<tr class="adresse">` but with no luck

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Could you post the relevant code here?

Comment: `$('tr.adresse').hide();` is working just fine here. The problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided works fine when run on that page - are you trying to run this on page-load?  If so, you may be trying to run the code before `tr.adresse` exists on the page.  If so, this should do the trick:

```
$(function () {
  $('tr.adresse').hide();
});
```

Note: `$(function...)` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function...);`

Comment: are you trying to run this on page-load? Yes thanks for your sugestion ill try that

Comment: Thanks Robert that workd. Now i youst have to figure out how to toggel the show hide state with the radion buttons

Comment: @JesperMøller Check my answer above for that

Comment: @Dark $('tr.adresse').hide(); was hat i tryde  the $(function () { did the trick now the tr is hidden wen the page is loaded. Now im trying to figure out how to toggel the show hide state with the radion buttons

Comment: You can use `$('tr.adresse').toggle()` to toggle show/hide functionality. (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @JesperMøller have you read my answer to your question? Scroll down. It explains how to toggle the show/hide with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

This will hide and show the row according to the radio buttons:

```
$("tr.adresse").hide();

$("input[name=levering]").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "leveret"){
     $("tr.adresse").show();
  }else{
     $("tr.adresse").hide();
  }
});
```